# Netbeans -- Sources are not writeable

Tags: linux, netbeans, linux-mint

I installed Netbeans on `Mint` and when I try to create a project at `/var/www/html/` it gives me error `Sources are not writeable`

I have changed the permissions of html to 775 but still getting this error
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem but on the Internet I couldn't find any proper solution.
First make sure your account is member of the group

> www-data

```
sudo usermod -a -G groupName userName
```

It's necessary to do so, but that's not 100% of the whole procedure. I went the "easy way" for the rest:

```
sudo nautilus #or whatever you use with Mint...
```

Then open the properties of your public_html folder and you'll encounter something like this:
[image]

Sorry, it's in German...

- Besitzer: Owner
- Zugriff: Access
- Dateien erstellen und löschen: Create files and delete
- Auf Dateien zugreifen: Access files (only)

As seen the group www-data has only insufficient rights. Give the group full access and the problem no longer exists...